# Error converting data type nvarchar to float

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the following error in my code.

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

My code on button click is

```
 protected void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlParameter LatParam;
        SqlParameter LngParam;


    if (zipcode.Text != "")
    {
        litAddress.Text = "";
        litAddress1.Text = "";
        string addressstring = zipcode.Text;


        string connstring = "Data Source=win2008-2;Initial Catalog=h1tm11;User ID=sa;Password=#1cub3123*;Persist Security Info=True;";


        string SQL1 = "SELECT *, 6371.01 * ACOS( SIN( @lat*PI()/180 ) * SIN( store_lat*PI()/180 ) + COS( @lat*PI()/180 ) * COS( store_lat*PI()/180 ) * COS( (store_long*PI()/180) - (@lng*PI()/180) ) ) AS distance from storelocator where 6371.01 * ACOS( SIN( @lat*PI()/180 ) * SIN( store_lat*PI()/180 ) + COS( @lng*PI()/180 ) * COS( store_lat*PI()/180 ) * COS( (store_long*PI()/180) - (@lng*PI()/180) ) ) < '" + ddl_distance.SelectedItem.Value + "' order by distance asc;";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(SQL1, conn);
        LatParam = new SqlParameter();
        LatParam.ParameterName = "@lat";
        LatParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        LatParam.Value =  "select lat from tbl_pincode where codes='" + zipcode.Text + "';";

        LngParam = new SqlParameter();
        LngParam.ParameterName = "@lng";
        LngParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        LngParam.Value ="select lat from tbl_pincode where  codes='" + zipcode.Text + "';";



        comm.Parameters.Add(LatParam);
        comm.Parameters.Add(LngParam);





        SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);


            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string area = reader["lat"].ToString();
                string codes =reader["lng"].ToString();



                litAddress.Text += area;
                litAddress1.Text += codes;




            }



    }
```

The datatype in the table are nvarchar for latitude,longitude and pincodes.

Thanks,

Comment: Unrelated to nvarchar/float, but you should ***really*** be using parameters rather than concatenation - you could be exposing yourself hugely to SQL injection here

Comment: Please read this: [SQL Injection Attacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx)

Comment: Please indicate which line throws the exception

Comment: You're doing a little Bobby Tables here, aren't you?

Comment: At least add some effort to code formatting :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think your error is with your select statement.

You are trying to perform calculations on nvarchar values. You either need to change the data types, or perform a Cast within your select statement.

For example...

```
CAST (lat AS float)
```

A section from your select statement for example should be...

```
ACOS( SIN( CAST ((@lat) AS float) * PI() / 180 )
```

NOTE: With the Cast method you will need to make sure that all you data values are numeric so there will be no cast exceptions

Comment: I modified my query according to your suggestion but the error persists.

Comment: @asifa: OK, and did it work? And did you apply the cast to all required values? it may also be worth adding brackets to the values too - this will ensure the select statements are run independently, for example... `CAST ((@lat) AS float)`

Comment: Did you get a different exception? What is your select statement? Are you sure all of your values are able to be converted to floats? Also, perhaps try the full statement in SQL Management Studio as it will provide better debugging

Comment: i want to show u my entire query where can i paste it. plz help i m new with it.

Comment: @asifa: OK, the query looks fine to me. Is it that same exception? and are you sure that all possible values are valid numbers? You cannot have any null values either

Comment: yes it is the same exception. All the possible values are valid numbers

Comment: @asifa. I cannot debug it for your. Try and run it in SQL Management Studio, also try and limit it to only returning one result. Get that working first and them test on more than one (i.e. make your WHERE clause more restrictive, maybe add an ID = 1 to ensure only one result)

Comment: Plz check this http://paste.pocoo.org/show/535577/. I think i need to convert this also.How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Your `@lat` etc contain string values, which **happen** to contain TSQL, but the server doesn't care about that - the server just considers it as a string. You then perform math operations, `@lat*PI()/180`, where `@lat` is a string like `select lat from tbl_pincode where codes=...blah...`. The server does not evaluate them - they are just strings.

What you *should* do, is something like:

```
declare @lat numeric, @long numeric -- replace with correct data types
select @lat = [lat], @long = [long] from tbl_pincode where codes=@zipcode
-- your math work here
```

and add a parameter called `zipcode` to the command, with the desired value.

Comment: Plz tell me how to solve it. I tried converting it to float and casting it but no luck.

Comment: converting **what** to float and casting **what** ?

Comment: @asifa that doesn't show me where lat/long are coming from, etc

Comment: @asifa if the value of `@lat` is still your TSQL then that **cannot** work - please read text I wrote

Comment: @asifa you haven't read what I wrote; please: `select @lat=[lat] from tbl_pincode where code {blah blah}` is **not** a numeric value; the server does not *execute* this; it is just an opaque string. I explained to add, instead, the `zipcode` as the parameter, and to look up the `@lat` etc **inside** the TSQL.

Comment: @asifa I already did... you just haven't made any change I suggested

Answer (score 0):

Because you're multiplying a nvarchar type parameter by Pi.

And even if the query was correct, you would still be multiplying a latitude or longitude value (which you say also are of type nvarchar) by Pi.