# invalid column name (lat,lat,lng,lat,lat,lng) in sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, latitude-longitude

```
protected void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (zipcode.Text != "")
    {
        litAddress.Text = "";
        litAddress1.Text = "";
        string addressstring = zipcode.Text;

        SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=win2008-2;Initial Catalog=h1tm11;User ID=sa;Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select lat,lng from tbl_pincode where codes='" + addressstring + "'", conn1);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(table);

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            string lat = row["lat"].ToString();
            string lng = row["lng"].ToString();

            string connstring = "Data Source=win2008-2;Initial Catalog=h1tm11;User ID=sa;Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
            string SQL1 = "SELECT  *, 6371.01 * ACOS( SIN( CAST((lat) AS float)*PI()/180 ) * SIN( CAST((store_lat) AS float)*PI()/180 ) + COS( CAST((lat) AS float)*PI()/180 ) * COS( CAST((store_lat) AS float)*PI()/180 ) * COS( (CAST((store_long) AS float)*PI()/180) - (CAST((lng) AS float)*PI()/180) ) ) AS distance from storelocator where 6371.01 * ACOS( SIN(CAST((lat) AS float)*PI()/180 ) * SIN( CAST((store_lat) AS float)*PI()/180 ) + COS(CAST((lat) AS float)*PI()/180 ) * COS( CAST((store_lat) AS float)*PI()/180 ) * COS( (CAST((store_long) AS float)*PI()/180) - (CAST((lng) AS float)*PI()/180) ) ) < '" + ddl_distance.SelectedItem.Value + "' order by distance asc;";
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(SQL1, conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string area = reader["store_name"].ToString();
                string codes = reader["store_address1"].ToString();
                litAddress.Text += area + "<br>";
                litAddress1.Text += codes + "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an invalid column name lat,lat,lng,lat,lat,lng error.I think it is not taking the `lat`,`lng` value in the sql query, but I'm passing it. I have also converted the string to float. The datafield in my database is `nvarchar` for `lat`,`lng`,`store_lat` and `store_long`. I don't know why.

Comment: Does store locator have lat and lng fields ? Why is ddl_distance value in quotes ? Why not first start off by using **parameters**  Ohh it seems you were already [warned about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878026/error-converting-data-type-nvarchar-to-float)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to Sql Injection.

Comment: Are you sure your sql query is correct? And there may be some conversion problem!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

u cross check once, all the column name. and try to rename with good naming convention, so that it will not lead to error.

this is not the right way to add parameter to your query, it will be error prone.. [Exploits of SqlInjectio](http://xkcd.com/327/) ,
you should use parameterized query. and also dont use

```
SELECT * from table name ,
```

you use how much column needed to display your logic, it will help to speed up the processing.

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select lat,lng from tbl_pincode wherecodes=@address", conn1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address",  addressstring ); 
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(table);
```

Comment: you need to execute it . and read using SqlDatareader, check updated ans

Answer (score 0):

You should write sql query like,

```
  string lat = row["lat"].ToString();
  string lng = row["lng"].ToString();
  string SQL1 = "SELECT  *, 6371.01 * CAST("+lat+" AS float)*PI()/180 From YourTable order by distance asc;";
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply.
Please Try this
"SELECT  *, 6371.01 * Convert(decimal(12,2),"+lat+")*PI()/180 From YourTable order by distance asc";